# Reset Oracle Apex admin password

Tags: oracle-apex

I have 2 Apexes installed on this server, I would like to reset password for the 2nd Apex, how would I do this? I tried

> $ sqlplus sys/123456 as sysdba
>
> SQL> @apxxepwd password

But it only reset the first Apex, how would I reset the 2nd apex?

The tnsnames.ora file looks like this

```
DATABASE1 =

(DESCRIPTION =

(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = the_database_server)(PORT = 1521))

(CONNECT_DATA =

(SERVICE_NAME = DATABASE1)

)

)

DATABASE2 =

(DESCRIPTION =

(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = the_database_server)(PORT = 1521))

(CONNECT_DATA =

(SERVICE_NAME = DATABASE2)

)

)
```

How do I connect to Database2? 
sqlplus sys as sysdba ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default database you are connecting to is defined by the ORACLE_SID environment variable.

But you can also specify which DB you're going to connect to by adding @... after the password.

```
connect sys/123456@database2 as sysdba
```

But you don't even need to set up the TNSNAMES.ora. You could also use "easy connect" by simply putting host/SID behind the @:

```
connect sys/123456@host/SID as sysdba
```

Note that "easy connect" can also be turned off in your SQLNET.ora (it's on by default in 10g clients and above i think).